# pywinauto: Сложности однозначной идентификации элементов

Tags: pywinauto

Методом `print_control_identifiers()` определено, что существуют два элемента с одинаковыми описаниями:

Первый:

> Button - 'Закрыть'    (L978, T740, R1030, B762)  | ['Закрыть',
> 'ЗакрытьButton', 'Button51', 'Закрыть0', 'Закрыть1', 'ЗакрытьButton0',
> 'ЗакрытьButton1']  | child_window(**title="Закрыть",
> control_type="Button**")

Второй:

> Button - 'Закрыть'    (L1014, T190, R1031, B207)  | ['Закрыть2',
> 'ЗакрытьButton2', 'Button55']  | child_window(**title="Закрыть",
> control_type="Button"**)

Из-за того, что подобных элементов более одного, метод `child_window()` не может идентифицировать необходимый, то есть первый, элемент.

У искомых элементов есть родительские элементы, которые в логе отображаются так:

> Toolbar - ''    (L302, T190, R1032, B208)
> | ['Toolbar11', 'ToolbarРазвернуть', 'ToolbarСвернуть', 'ToolbarЗакрыть']

Соответственно, "прицепиться" к ним не получается. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать в `child_window(parent=parent_wrapper, ...)`, а можно индекс элемента среди найденных по остальным критериям: `child_window(..., found_index=0)`.

Comment: Как получить индекс элемента? Где индекс сей отображается в логе метода print_control_identifiers()?

Comment: Никак, это индекс среди найденных. В будущей версии будет метод `.find_all()`, который вернёт список. А сейчас придётся тупо перебирать found_index от нуля до нужного. Это не свойство элемента.